# Importing tkinter in Python2.7 on Mac

Tags: python, eclipse, tkinter, python-2.7

I recently installed Python2.7 on MacOs 10.6.8. I'm having a problem importing tkinter. I keep gettig this 'no matching architecture in universal wrapper' message which means that the version of Tkinter is incorrect.

What I did, I followed the instructions [here](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/), downloaded ActiveTcl 8.5.11 for 32/64bits MacOs architecure and installed it, but nothing really changed. I deleted and reinstalled the interpreter afet that too.

What should I do?

Comment: Which version of Python you have installed. Have you installed it from python.org with both 32/64 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install python which can support both 32bit & 64 bit architecture from

http://python.org/download/releases/2.7.2/

Also after installing TCL from the link that you have mentioned. You can try the following to check which architecture is suitable

```
arch -i386 /path/to/python/executable
from Tkinter import *
```

or

```
arch -x86_64 /path/to/python/executable
from Tkinter import *
```

This may help you resolve the issue.

Note from the link: As of this writing, the Python 3.2.x 64-bit/32-bit and 2.7.x 64-bit/32-bit Mac OS X installers are built with Intel-64 (x86_64) and Intel-32 (i386) architectures and a minimum deployment target of Mac OS X 10.6. The Apple 8.5.9 and ActiveTcl 8.5.11 releases discussed below are compatible with these installers.

Comment: that's interesting, when I run in the console platform.architecture() I get '64bit', but when I run arch in the terminal the result is i386. Is there some conflict here?

Comment: @sigma.z.1980 : Depending from where you installed, you can have both flavor. Also you need to check for sys.maxint as platform.architecture () for Mac does not return correct results